# code igniter SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, pagination

How to get total number of rows for particular query and also limiting the query results to 10 rows. For example. I've a table called sample. It has 400 rows. On running a query like where name = "%Sam%" it returns me 213 rows. Now I'l be taking only first 10 rows and displaying the result to user but I need the total rows returned. How should I need to do it in code igniter?

```
SELECT
        SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM
        sample
WHERE
        name like "%sam%"
```

like this?
How to retrieve total number counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a second query to get the results of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

That will return the value found using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. You may find using an alias easier for getting the result, though:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS num_results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two query one to get the count and the other return the limited result.

Like in your model create a function that only returns the count variable

and create a second function that generates the paginated results.

eg..

```
public function count($where){
        $query = $this->db->query("select count(id) as count from clients $where");
        return $query->row('count');
        }
}

public function limit($sidx,$sord,$start,$limit,$where){
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from clients $where ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result_array();
        }
}
```

And here goes the controller code

$where = // calculated

```
$count = count($this->model->count($where));

        if( $count > 0 ) { $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); } else { $total_pages = 0; }

        if ($page > $total_pages) $page = $total_pages; 


        $start = $limit * $page - $limit;


        $users = $this->model->limit($sidx,$sord,$start,$limit,$where);
```

.................